# The number of ways to have a sum of $n$ natural numbers equal to $k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{k+1}{i-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$, where $n$ and $k$ are fixed natural numbers. This expression is for the number of ways to have a sum of positive or equal to zero natural numbers $\sum^n_{i=1} a_i$ equal to $k$. First factor is the number of ways to pick the boxes where I put my '$1$'s, the second factor is  the number of ways to have these $k$ '$1$'s put into the selected number of boxes (using the stars and bars technique). The right hand side is in the answer. I can't figure out the transition.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like the $k+1$ entry maybe should be $k-1$ in order to fulfill your explanation (i.e. $i$ is the number of non-empty boxes). The RHS is just the usual stars and bars formula for the number of ways to write $k$ as an ordered sum of $n$ non-negative integers.

Comment: @Ned i think i might have found what i did wrong - since the numbers can be 0, we can put more than one bar in one space, and so the number of spaces available doesnt decrease with putting another bar, and so the formula will be easier. I'll try to figure it out now

Comment: @Ned think it should be $(k+1)^{i-1}$ instead of the second factor. I still think there should $k+1$, since it appears to me that this is indeed the number of spaces for where to put bars. Edit: well, it doesnt seem to be the answer as well

Comment: Plug in some low numbers to check whatever formula you think is right before trying to write a general derivation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the given expression which is being asked to prove is not correct.

for example put n=4 and k=2
 the expression in LHS becomes 35 while RHS is only 10

so... please recheck the question.
I'm writing this here as I don't have the required reputation to comment on your question.